# How to upload a picture in firebase storage and get it url in firebase document field

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I successfully upload the picture by using image picker library, but am unable to upload it in firebase storage.

Here is my code

```
launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);
    
      if (response.didcancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.custombutton);
      } else {
       
       //Convert image to base64
        source = JSON.stringify(response.assets[0].uri);
        console.log('Image in Base64 is  ', JSON.stringify(response.assets[0].uri));
        RNFS.readFile(response.assets[0].uri, 'base64')
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res); // The base64 string
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[It's documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files). Once you get the download URL, it's just `.update` it into an existing firestore document, or `set` to create a new one.

```
// Create the file metadata
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

// Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  (snapshot) => {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // A full list of error codes is available at
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'storage/unauthorized':
        // User doesn't have permission to access the object
        break;
      case 'storage/canceled':
        // User canceled the upload
        break;

      // ...

      case 'storage/unknown':
        // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
        break;
    }
  }, 
  () => {
    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
```